# Бинарный поиск. Не получается найти элемент

Tags: алгоритм, поиск

Бинарный поиск находит только 1 элемент, по отладке посмотрел, он не успевает найти элемент если он не первый, не могу найти ошибку. Помогите, кому не сложно.

```
//Проверка ввода чисел. Алгоритм поисков: бинарного, индексно-последовательного, линейного.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
const int SIZE = 20;

struct Table {
    int key;
    int info;
};
//ввод только чисел
void inittable(Table *table) {
    char digit[10], *p = digit;
    bool cht = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        cout << "\nВведите ключ(целое число): ";    cin >> digit;
        while (*p) 
            if (!isdigit(*p++)) {
                cht = false;
                break;
            }
            else cht = true;
            if(cht)
                table[i].key = atoi(digit);
            else {
                cout << "\nВвели не целое число! \nПовторите ввод: ";
                cin >> digit;
                table[i].key = atoi(digit);
            }

            p = digit;

        cout << "\nВведите инфо. поле(целое число): ";  cin >> digit;
        while (*p)
            if (!isdigit(*p++)) {
                cht = false;
                break;
            }
            else cht = true;
        if (cht)
            table[i].info = atoi(digit);
        else {
            cout << "\nВвели не целое число! \nПовторите ввод: ";
            cin >> digit;
            table[i].info = atoi(digit);
        }

        p = digit;
    }
}
//бинарный поиск
void binsearch(Table *table) {
    int left = 0, right = 5;
    int mid, search = -1;
    int key = 0; //ключ по которому ищем

    cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\tБИНАРНЫЙ ПОИСК" << "\n\nВведите ключ: "; cin >> key;

    while(left < right) {
        mid = (left + right) / 2;

        if (table[mid].key == key) {
            search = mid;
            break;
        }

        if ( key < table[mid].key )
            right = mid - 1;
        else
            left = mid + 1;
    }

    if (search == -1)
        cout << "\nИскомого ключа не существует в таблице!";
    else
        cout << "\n\n" << "Двоичный поиск по ключу: " << table[search].key << ", информационное поле данному ключу: " << table[search].info;
}

void print(Table *table) {
    system("cls");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
        cout << "\nKey: " << table[i].key << "\t\tInfo: " << table[i].info;;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    Table table[SIZE];

    inittable(table);
    print(table);

    binsearch(table);

    cout << "\n\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что такое "только 1 элемент"? Только один элемент? Или только первый элемент? Что за манера вставлять числа в текст в контекстах, где их смысловое значение неоднозначно?

Comment: @AnT, я думаю, когда речь идет об алгоритме, то и так понятно

Comment: В алгоритме может быть и так, и так. Поэтому я в упор не вижу, как тут нам помогает то, что речь идет об алгоритме.

Comment: Я ведь написал дальше, что не успевает найти никакой, кроме первого, если уж вас так смутила - 1, то дальше становится все равно все понятно

Answer (score 0):

```
Переделал не много твой алгоритм. 
void binsearch(Table *table) {
int left = 0, right = 5;
int mid, search = -1;
int key = 0; //ключ по которому ищем

cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\tБИНАРНЫЙ ПОИСК" << "\n\nВведите ключ: "; cin >> key;

while(right - left > 1) {
    mid = (left + right) / 2;

    if (table[mid].key == key) {
        search = mid;
        break;
    }

    if ( key < table[mid].key )
        right = mid - 1;
    else
        left = mid + 1;
}
for(int i = left; i <= right; i++)
{
  if (table[i].key == key) {
        search = mid;
        break;
    }
}
if (search == -1)
    cout << "\nИскомого ключа не существует в таблице!";
else
    cout << "\n\n" << "Двоичный поиск по ключу: " << table[search].key << ", информационное поле данному ключу: " << table[search].info;
```

}